# Core Data in Unit tests with RZVinyl

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, core-data

Just to give a bit of backdrop: I recently started working on unit tests for the code that had been developed and maintained by some other company. My intention is to write the test cases without touching the application code .

Now coming to the problem: How can one get a reference to the CoreData stack of the application within the unit tests' target. After every service call, the response is stored in the persistent store of CoreData. I want to validate it from the unit tests class. I tried accessing the CoreData stack from unit tests but for some reason it was coming as nil after the code got compiled. Here's the piece of code in my setUp method.

```
- (void)setUpDataBase 
{

 RZCoreDataStack *stack = [[RZCoreDataStack alloc] initWithModelName:@"Skillsoft"
                                                      configuration:nil
                                                          storeType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                           storeURL:nil
                                                            options:RZCoreDataStackOptionDeleteDatabaseIfUnreadable];
NSAssert(stack != nil, @"Failed to create CoreData stack");
stack.mainManagedObjectContext.parentContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
[RZCoreDataStack setDefaultStack:stack];
RZCoreDataStack *setStack = [RZCoreDataStack defaultStack];
NSLog(@"setStack Details >>> %@",setStack.description);
}

+ (RZCoreDataStack *)defaultStack
{
if ( s_defaultStack == nil ) {
    RZVLogInfo(@"The default stack has been accessed without being configured. Creating a new default stack with the default options.");
  //      //  s_defaultStack = [[RZCoreDataStack alloc] initWithModelName:nil
//                                                      configuration:nil



    s_defaultStack = [[RZCoreDataStack alloc] initWithModelName:@"Skillsoft"
                                                  configuration:nil
                                                      storeType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                       storeURL:nil
                                                        options:RZCoreDataStackOptionDeleteDatabaseIfUnreadable];
    s_defaultStack.mainManagedObjectContext.parentContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
  }
return s_defaultStack;
 }`
```

The default stack is a static variable and is coming as nil ... I am assuming that 2 sets of static variables are being created one in application scope and other in unit tests scope ... I just want to write unit test case for a method in UIView controller that, in turn, makes a service call in scope of another layer. I want to validate it by getting a reference to CoreData in app and check if the data is being persisted properly... What is the right way to proceed with that ...

I have seen a couple of StackOverflow posts which suggests to create one's own CoreData stack in the setUp method, but with that I would need to persist the data in the same stack which I don't want to do at this moment ..

I could see that app delegate gets called when your run the unit test cases which in turn initialises quite a few objects in my project ..In order to avoid that , i have made a change in the main file itself to call testing app delegate instead of app's main delegate based on the target .. So all the initializations of the objects are being done in the unit tests..

Please suggest me the right approach to proceed...

P.S For CoreData access, the application uses a third party library named RZVinyl, which kinda made things even more complex for me ..

P.P.S My English is weak, so please let me know if I'm not clear in my explanation. I will update the problem statement..